# update layout using custom layout handles

Tags: layout, xml

i'm fairly new to magento, so i might not get all terms right. it's also possible that i haven't fully understood the magento internals which work through layouts and templates to print a webpage to the customer.
i followed some simple tutorial to add a module to magento which provides me three additional options too choose from when setting the page_layout for categories/products.
so far so good. the entries show up in admin backend and the templates i associated to these page_layouts are correctly loaded if i browse to a custom layout category.

i've removed and added plenty of blocks via local.xml. i've been using `<default>` (which targets all layouts iirc) and `<catalog_category_default>` (which is parsed when browsing a category). so in know how to use  and "`<block type="foo/myblock" name="my.precious.block" />` to remove or display a block.

now i want to add a block to one of my custom layouts.
my /magento/app/code/local/Foo/Layout/etc/config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Layout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Foo_Layout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <foo_category_a module="page" translate="label">
                    <label>CustomCategory (A)</label>
                    <template>page/category_a.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>foo_cat_a</layout_handle>
                    <update handle="foo_cat_a" />
                </foo_category_a>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

/app/etc/modules/Foo_Layout.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Layout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Foo_Layout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and my /app/design/frontend/default/foo/layout/local.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">  
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/foo.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="header">
            <remove name="topSearch" />
        </reference>

        <reference name="right">
            <remove name="right.permanent.callout" />
        </reference>

        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
        </reference>

        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>

    <!--
        category view mods
    -->
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
            <remove name="currency" />
            <remove name="tags_popular" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

    <foo_cat_a>
        <remove name="products.info" />
    </foo_cat_a>
</layout>
```

so i have:
layouts added: check
selectable in admin: check
correctly loading the specified templates: check
being able to add blocks to custom layout: fail :(

what am i missing here? i searched the web up and down, tried many different locations for layout-definition and the layout-update-code, but nothing worked so far.

the predefined handles work well (e.g. `<catalog_category_default>`) but not those defined by me.

greetings
patrick

Comment: FYI, because you see your module working, its config file must be in named *`config.xml`* not *`conf.xml`*.

Comment: And, where is `foo_cat_a` handle being applied? How do you think it should work? It won't be merged to the layout instructions without being added to the layout update object via PHP or via an `<update />` directive in another handle.

Comment: actually my config.xml is named "config.xml" only a typo in my qustion. same goes for the <update /> directive. the xml i posted here is a version where i had the <update /> removed again, because it did not work. i've edited my post, and again added it. but it still does not work...

Comment: This issue is  well explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249894/magento-1-7-how-to-use-the-page-layout-handle - for those who need the selected Page Layout handle of a category to be set, I have added this to my GlobalHanle extension. https://github.com/ProxiBlue/GlobalHandle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<update handle="foo_cat_a" />` might not work because it is likely being parsed before the handle (which typically adds the **product.info** block handle) is being parsed.

To debug handle load/merge order you can follow the directions I have specified [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95/debugging-layout-loading)

Comment: is there any way to get around that or at least debug this?

Comment: Edited in a link to debug method.

Comment: your debug method did an awesome work for me. i figured out that no handles where called or even added. and because i had to learn about observers i also found a way to add layout-handles, which are working fine now. thank you!