# Magento front end page characters /**/ at top of page

Tags: xml, css

On my Magento 1.6.2.0 http://nilandsplace.com I have `/**/`
loading before page content and some gray space just under the Logo header and behind the menu. I was working on removing a Google Translate floating box that was in the way of my AddThis buttons. Removing the Script did not seem to remove the "Website Translator" [image: Translate buttom]
It took a lot of file exploring to finally get it gone from my Magento. I am sure during this effort I introduced the `/**/` but I can't remember or find where it is? The View source shows the error:

```
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
/*<script type="text/javascript">var Translator = new Translate({"Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.":"Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or underscores (_) in this field, first character must be a letter."});</script>*/
```

It should look like this:

```
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">var Translator = new Translate({"Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.":"Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or underscores (_) in this field, first character must be a letter."});</script>
```

I have downloaded the whole site and database but I can't find `/*<script ...</script>*/
I have done file compassion to my local copy made in`July that does not have the error. I have done many kinds of string searches with no joy.
Firebug shows the error, but not were it comes from.
I added some troubleshooting extensions to my Magento only to discover the page is not loading right at all. On my live site I have only 2 layout updates and my local copy has 48. Somehow all the layout updates are merged into to 1 on my live site.
 I have been trying to learn how a page is loaded in Magento Layout and Template, but can't seem to find who's on first and whats on second. What loads the page and what layout is first? I have looked in /app/design/frontend/... /base, /default, /enterprise and /pro. The last 2 I don't know why they are there for Magento CE.How do I figure what order things load?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to find the error at this link http://wrightcreativelabs.com/magento-simplexml_load_string-error-troubleshooting/

I thought I was troubleshooting a different error in my Magento system.log but it turned out to be the error this question was about. The big secret was

> Open up Config.php (located at /lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php) and
>   go to line 510:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);
```

> Below this line, add the following:

```
if(!$xml){ Mage::log($string); }
```

after refreshing the cache, I got this in my log file

```
2014-08-30T16:45:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():          ^  in /home/niland55/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2014-08-30T16:45:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<menu>
<!---        <mgtcommerce translate="title" module="mgt_base">
        <title>Mgt-Commerce.com</title>
        <sort_order>75</sort_order>
        <action>adminhtml/mgt</action>
   </mgtcommerce> --->
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <mgt_base>
                                    <title>Mgt-Commerce.com - Module Information</title>
                                </mgt_base>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

This allowed me to find the offending file and I deleted the bad comment:

```
<!---        <mgtcommerce translate="title" module="mgt_base">
        <title>Mgt-Commerce.com</title>
        <sort_order>75</sort_order>
        <action>adminhtml/mgt</action>
   </mgtcommerce> --->
```

**And everything was back to normal**

Answer (score 0):

The question for loading sequence has already been answered by Ben Marks at this url:

[Debugging layout XML loading](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95/debugging-layout-loading)

He explains how to get update handle and loaded block, by logging this you will also find out the sequence in which your page loads. If you are looking for a block that is a direct child of the page you could also take a look at your page-xmls.

To check in what block a piece of code exist you can turn on template path hints and check in the html source to see what block / template contains the code, alltough this is not easy when you have messy html / alot of childblocks.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look in: Mage_Core_Helper_Js::getTranslatorScript()

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Js.php