# local.xml column layout not having an effect - how to fix or debug?

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, local.xml

My local.xml is not affecting my product page layout. Any idea how to debug it or, better yet, fix it?

I have this in my theme/local.xml.

```
...
    </default>
<catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="root"><!-- was set to pages/2columns-right.phtml, changing it does nothing -->
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>pages/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
...
```

Changing it has no effect. Another developer has used per-product layout updates to "fix" the problem, but I think the best solution is to get the xml directive to work, rather than fill up the database with 1 million new entries.

I found [this magento.stackexchange answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97/2396) on how to trace the layout building process, but it isn't helping me find the actual problem.

I've inserted this into the top of my `theme/product/view.phtml`:

```
<pre><?php var_dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()); ?></pre>
```

The output is essentially the same for a product that has no per-product layout update applied vs one that does have one applied:

1.) no per-product layout applied:

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "default"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "STORE_default"
  [2]=>
  string(28) "THEME_frontend_default_mytheme"
  [3]=>
  string(20) "catalog_product_view"
  [4]=>
  string(19) "PRODUCT_TYPE_simple"
  [5]=>
  string(14) "PRODUCT_157610"
  [6]=>
  string(19) "customer_logged_out"
  [7]=>
  string(9) "MAP_popup"
  [8]=>
  string(19) "MAP_price_msrp_item"
  [9]=>
  string(14) "SHORTCUT_popup"
  [10]=>
  string(17) "SHORTCUT_uk_popup"
}
```

2.) per-product layout applied (visible in the admin product page under Design/Page Layout: "2 columns with right bar")

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "default"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "STORE_default"
  [2]=>
  string(28) "THEME_frontend_default_mytheme"
  [3]=>
  string(20) "catalog_product_view"
  [4]=>
  string(19) "PRODUCT_TYPE_simple"
  [5]=>
  string(12) "PRODUCT_2563"
  [6]=>
  string(19) "customer_logged_out"
  [7]=>
  string(9) "MAP_popup"
  [8]=>
  string(19) "MAP_price_msrp_item"
  [9]=>
  string(14) "SHORTCUT_popup"
  [10]=>
  string(17) "SHORTCUT_uk_popup"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo, it's `page/2columns-left.phtml` not `pages/2columns-left.phtml`.

Answer (score 0):

use following code in your local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```