# How to get Login or Create Account into a BLOCK?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add this code in block in this way `<block type="">` so that I can call this code using blocks in my `local.xml` file actually this code is called in `header.phtml` the below code outputs this see the image but I don't want to display it there but only in particular pages

[image]

```
<div class="right clearfix <?php echo ($cart_pos == 'top' && $switcher_pos == 'top') ? 'header-top-both' : '' ?>">
                <?php if ($cart_pos == 'top') echo $cart_html; ?>
                <?php if ($switcher_pos == 'top') echo $switcher_html; ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $c1 ?>">
                <?php $helper = Mage::helper('customer'); ?>
                    <p class="login-link <?php if ($switcher_pos != 'top' && $cart_pos != 'top') echo 'static' ?>">
                        <?php if ($helper->isLoggedIn()): ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $helper->getLogoutUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Logout');?></a>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $helper->getLoginUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Login');?></a> <?php echo $this->__('or') ?> <a href="<?php echo $helper->getRegisterUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('create an account');?></a>.
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                         <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating blocks you can do this by placing the code at the required pages coz the above process may/may not work all times(not worked for me) so follow this procedure.

1. Comment the code(copy first) in `header.phtml` file so that it will
   not be visible in header section.
2. Now place this code in the required pages which you want to display
       login and create account for example if you want to show in products
       page put this code in `template->catalog->Products list.phtml and view.phtml` so that it will be visible in products page the same
       process for all the other pages which you require.

NOTE:Not a recommended process but solved my problem.

Comment: actually for me too the above answers not worked tried all those now let me try your answer.

Comment: Oh my... This worked for me :) since last week iam fighting for this and now this solved.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the data from the Block and put them into a single template:

```
<p class="login-link <?php if ($switcher_pos != 'top' && $cart_pos != 'top') echo 'static' ?>">
    <?php if ($helper->isLoggedIn()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getLogoutUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Logout');?></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getLoginUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Login');?></a> <?php echo $this->__('or') ?> <a href="<?php echo $helper->getRegisterUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('create an account');?></a>.
    <?php endif; ?> 
</p>
```

in you layout files you can use it with:

```
<block type="core/template" name="customer_login_or_create" template="path/to/template.phtml"/>
```

wether the block's type you will add the new template is core/text_list it will be outputted automatically, otherwise you have to echo it by yourself;

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_login_or_create');?>
```

hope that helps.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

In **app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/template/page/html/** create a new file called `customlogin.phtml` and add the following code:

```
<div class="custom-login">
    <?php $helper = Mage::helper('customer'); ?>
        <p class="login-link <?php if ($switcher_pos != 'top' && $cart_pos != 'top') echo 'static' ?>">
            <?php if ($helper->isLoggedIn()): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $helper->getLogoutUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Logout');?></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $helper->getLoginUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Login');?></a> <?php echo $this->__('or') ?> <a href="<?php echo $helper->getRegisterUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('create an account');?></a>.
            <?php endif; ?> 
            <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
        </p>
    <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
</div>
```

Now for the page(s) that you would like the Login/Create an Account to be displayed use Layout Update XML in the Admin Panel.

*For example:*

If you would like to display this in the right side bar of the Customer Service page, open that page via **CMS** > **Pages** and go to the "Design" tab. Under the Page Layout section add the following code in the Layout Update XML field:

```
<reference name="right">

        <block type="core/template" name="block.custom.login" template="page/html/customlogin.phtml" before="-">

                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block.custom.login</block_id></action>

        </block>

</reference>
```

This will display the Login/Create an Account at the top of the right sidebar of the Customer Service page. You may need some css to make it look perfect. Just add this at the bottom of the .css file of your preference.

Also, don't forget to remove the relevant code from your `header.phtml` file

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the Layout Handlers, conditioning for pages is what they are for.

Remove the existing header block in the default handler in `page.xml` layout reference via your `local.xml` layout, and add the block you are wanting to display under the appropriate layout handlers in the `local.xml` as well.

[image]

> Handle Handle (diagram 1) is an identifier by which the application
>   determines what to do with the updates nested by it.
>
> If the name of the handle is , then the application knows
>   that its nested updates must be loaded on almost all the pages of the
>   store prior to loading page-specific layout (We say 'almost all',
>   because some exceptional pages like the product image popup does not
>   load the layout in the  handle).
>
> If Magento finds handles other than , it will assign the
>   updates nested inside the handle to the according page specified by
>   the handle. For instance,  contain the layout
>   updates for the Product View page, while
>    contain those for the Compare Product
>   page. Handles are set-in-stone identifiers that as a designer with no
>   extensive understanding of Magento programming, should never need to
>   modify.

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts
- [Debugging layout XML loading](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95/debugging-layout-loading)
- http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout