# In config.xml file layout file is not working

Tags: magento-1.8

I have Config.xml file

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <blog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>AW_Blog</module>
                    <frontName>blog</frontName>
                </args>
            </blog>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <blog module="AW_Blog">
                    <file>aw_blog.xml</file>
                </blog>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <AW_Blog>
                    <files>
                        <default>AW_Blog.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </AW_Blog>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
```

In this Layout file not working "aw_blog.xml"

```
  <layout>
                <updates>
                    <blog module="AW_Blog">
                        <file>aw_blog.xml</file>
                    </blog>
                </updates>
            </layout>
```

Please check what is issue ?.

Thanks,

Comment: what is the error it gives? In the layout file, if u r using blocks, then use block type="core/template" instead of module name and block file name..

Comment: This link will help u to debug the issue http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95/debugging-layout-loading

Comment: i have changed <block type="core/template"> but still same issue

Comment: Check file permission and it should be 777.

Comment: changed file permission too @manik previously permission is(644) i have changed to (777)

Comment: You *did* flush the cache, right?

Comment: Can you post the full config.xml? As well as the layout file? Also can you update your question with the location of your layout file?